# How to detect collision between moving rigidbody cube and static empty object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and working on collision detection.

I have a rigidbody cube and an empty object with a cube mesh. The rigidbody cube moves with arrow keys and the empty object is static. Both have a box collider.

How do I detect collision between this empty object and the rigidbody cube?

I am wondering whether it should be OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter and how to use the correct command.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: On the empty object set the collider to "is Trigger" in the inspector and then in a script attached to that object, use OnTriggerEnter() - see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html ... The other cube needs the rigidbody for the OnTrigger events to fire.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to set the box collider component to the cube and to the empty  object with cube mesh. Then you can use this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour

{
    public PlayerMovement movement;
    public GAME_MANAGER GameManager;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Make sure you have set the tag of the obstacle to “Obstacle” and add this script to the player or the cube. Here,

```
movement.enabled = false;
```

You can apply you own logic according to your need.

Thanks